# Pandas groupby get row with max in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to get the row of a group that has the maximum value across multiple columns:

`pd.DataFrame([{'grouper': 'a', 'col1': 1, 'col2': 3, 'uniq_id': 1}, {'grouper': 'a', 'col1': 2, 'col2': 4, 'uniq_id': 2}, {'grouper': 'a', 'col1': 3, 'col2': 2, 'uniq_id': 3}])`

```
   col1  col2 grouper  uniq_id
0     1     3       a        1
1     2     4       a        2
2     3     2       a        3
```

In the above, I'm grouping by the "grouper" column. Within the "a" group, I want to get the row that has the max of `col1` and `col2`, in this case, when I group my DataFrame, I want to get the row with `uniq_id` of `2` because it has the highest value of col1/col2 with 4, so the outcome would be:

```
   col1  col2 grouper  uniq_id
1     2     4       a        2
```

In my actual example, I'm using timestamps, so I actually don't expect ties. But in the case of a tie, I am indifferent to which row I select in the group, so it would just be `first` of the group in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One more way you can try:

```
# find row wise max value
df['row_max'] = df[['col1','col2']].max(axis=1)

# filter rows from groups
df.loc[df.groupby('grouper')['row_max'].idxmax()]

   col1 col2 grouper uniq_id row_max
1    2    4     a        2     4
```

Later you can drop `row_max` using `df.drop('row_max', axis=1)`

Comment: A lot of great answers here! I thought this one worked best and was closest to what I was doing previously, by using the .max() of multiple columns. I just hadn't figured out the groupby and this does that for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC using `transform` then compare with original dataframe

```
g=df.groupby('grouper')
s1=g.col1.transform('max')
s2=g.col2.transform('max')
s=pd.concat([s1,s2],axis=1).max(1)

df.loc[df[['col1','col2']].eq(s,0).any(1)]
Out[89]: 
   col1  col2 grouper  uniq_id
1     2     4       a        2
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting approaches all around. Adding another one just to show the power of `apply` (which I'm a big fan of) and using some of the other mentioned methods.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"grouper": "a", "col1": 1, "col2": 3, "uniq_id": 1},
        {"grouper": "a", "col1": 2, "col2": 4, "uniq_id": 2},
        {"grouper": "a", "col1": 3, "col2": 2, "uniq_id": 3},
    ]
)

def find_max(grp):
    # find max value per row, then find index of row with max val
    max_row_idx = grp[["col1", "col2"]].max(axis=1).idxmax()
    return grp.loc[max_row_idx]

df.groupby("grouper").apply(find_max)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value  = pd.concat([df['col1'], df['col2']], axis = 0).max()
df.loc[(df['col1'] == value) | (df['col2'] == value), :]

  col1  col2 grouper uniq_id
1   2    4     a       2
```

This probably isn't the fastest way, but it will work in your case. Concat both the columns and find the max, then search the df for where either column equals the value.

Comment: I think you need consider groupby as well

Comment: Your right! For some reason in his example when I only saw 'a' I forgot that part of the question -__-

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy and pandas as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3],
          'col2': [3, 4, 2],
          'grouper': ['a', 'a', 'a'],
          'uniq_id': [1, 2, 3]})

df['temp'] = np.max([df.col1.values, df.col2.values],axis=0)
idx = df.groupby('grouper')['temp'].idxmax()
df.loc[idx].drop('temp',1)
   col1  col2 grouper  uniq_id
1     2     4       a        2
```